# Does using the past tense make the conversation more polite?

Tags: politeness

I am wondering if the past tense is used sometimes to increase the level of politeness in a conversation which occurs in present form. For example:

> お待たせしました

In that case, under which circumstances the past form of the verb is used to make the sentence polite? Also, which sort of difference it makes with the present polite form of the verb?

Comment: Maybe you will still want to ask the question with a different example, but usually お待たせしました is said after someone made someone wait, not as they're doing it, or before.

Comment: @Leebo True. I get the point about this sentence. Though I do not have the presence of mind for other examples, still for some time I have this doubt. I would like to know If there is some sort of principle about the subject?

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20966/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18253/7810